# Change href can't update the data which bind to ng-src or ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-href

Html

```
<div class="result" ng-controller="test">
    <div>{{result}}</div>
    <a ng-href="{{result}}"></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
App.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope){
    $scope.result = "www.google.com";
}
```

In a jquery file I can't modify because of some reason, some code changed the value of href, like:

```
$('.result>a').attr('href','www.youtube.com');
```

I want the value of $scope.result in the controller also changed from "www.google.com" to "www.youtube.com". But the result value in the `div` didn't change after the jquery code. Do I need write directive to watch the href attribute by myself? Or there are some other way to use ng-href? I try to write the directive by myself, but it didn't work. I hope you can give me a small example. Thanks :)

Update:

This is my directive, it didn't work, after something like $('.result>a').attr('href','www.youtube.com'), the console didn't print "change!" and the $scope.result didn't change:

```
APP.directive('result', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: "<div class='result'><a ng-href='{{ngModel}}' href=''></a></div>",
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var $element = $(element.children()[0]);
            scope.$watch($element.attr('href'), function(newValue) {
                console.log("change!");
                scope.ngModel = newValue;
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Update Again: Still can't work...

Html:

```
<div class="result">
    <a ng-href="{{result}}" ng-model="result" class="resulta"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
APP.directive('resulta', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.href, function(newValue) {
                console.log("change!");
                scope.ngModel = newValue;
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is one of the primary cases for a directive. What went wrong with the directive when you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for updating. What didn't work exactly?

Comment: I think maybe there is something wrong with the scope.$watch, but I can't find the problem...

Comment: The console never console the "change!" after $('.result>a').attr('href','www.youtube.com');

Comment: Right, so, the `element` in the link function is the element on the actual page, not including the template to be loaded. You would need another directive inside the anchor element of your template that can watch its own HREF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed create a custom directive to do it. See the example. I use transclude scope so you can put whatever you like in the link. I set 'replace: true' so the directive is removed and replaced with the `<a>`.

**UPDATE**
Using MutationObserver to watch for changes to the `<a href>`

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive("myHref", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          scope.$parent.result = mutation.target.href;
          scope.$apply();
        });
      });

      // configuration of the observer:
      var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
      };

      observer.observe(elem[0], config);

    },
    scope: {
      myHref: '='
    },
    template: '<a target="_blank" ng-transclude href="{{myHref}}"></a>'
  };
});

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.result = "http://www.yahoo.com";
  $scope.$watch('result', function() {
    alert($scope.result);
  });
});



setTimeout(function() {
  $('.result > a ').attr('href', 'http://www.youtube.com');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="result" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <my-href my-href="result">My Link</my-href>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried, but see the $scope.result still not change. You can see in: http://jsfiddle.net/castiel_zyf/0hL4ucxf/

Comment: yes I saw your changes after I uploaded my solution.

Comment: updated now with MutationObserver now updates the $scope.result

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really worked! But I am curious about why the function  like scope.$watch() didn't work, is there some problem in my code? Or the $watch function can't achieve the desired results like MutationObserver?

Comment: The jQuery function is called outside the control of AngularJS. This means, that all of the _magic_ that AngularJS does with calling watchers, etc. won't happen automatically. This article here [http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) explains it quite well. In fact after perusing it, I see I should have called `$apply` instead of `$digest`, and so I've changed it.